# Modifying variables in makefile

Tags: variables, makefile, gnu

I would like the make process to conditionally echo only on first target that is executed
In the following makefile, it should only print 'a', 'b', or 'goal'
Currently, since L doesn't get modified, it prints for any target that is executed.

I have done it with external temporary files and scripts, but I want to know if it is at all possible without external files/scripts?

```
L=1

goal: a b
ifeq ($(L),1)
        @echo goal
        @L=0
endif
        @echo done > goal

a:
ifeq ($(L),1)
        @echo a
        @L=0
endif
        @echo done > a

b:
ifeq ($(L),1)
        @echo b
        @L=0
endif
        @echo done > b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use ifeq etc. because these are *preprocessor* statements: they are executed as the makefile is read in.

In traditional make there is no way to do what you want, except through scripts and files as you've done.  If you're willing to be GNU make specific, and require a version of GNU make new enough to support the `$(eval ...)` function, then you can do it; something like:

```
SHOW := true
goal: a b
        $(if $(SHOW),@echo goal $(eval SHOW :=))
        @echo done > goal
a:
        $(if $(SHOW),@echo a $(eval SHOW :=))
        @echo done > a
b:
        $(if $(SHOW),@echo b $(eval SHOW :=))
        @echo done > b
```